# HTML displaying raw Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Posted below are the relevant HTML and JS code.

I am having trouble getting the respective values to correctly reflect in the HTML when the writeSessionValues function is called. Currently I have the first name and last name value set inside script tags, and instead of showing the raw JavaScript code in the respective area, it now doesn't display anything.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
   calcCart();
   // runs sessionTest function when regSubmit button is clicked
   document.getElementById("regSubmit").onclick = sessionTest();
   // runs calcCart function when fnBox, lnBox, groupBox, mailBox, phoneBox, or 
   // banquetBox input boxes are blurred
   document.getElementById("fnBox").onblur = calcCart();
   document.getElementById("lnBox").onblur = calcCart();
   document.getElementById("groupBox").onblur = calcCart();
   document.getElementById("mailBox").onblur = calcCart();
   document.getElementById("phoneBox").onblur = calcCart();
   document.getElementById("banquetBox").onblur = calcCart();
   // runs calcCart function when sessionBox selection is changed
   document.getElementById("sessionBox").onchange = calcCart();
   // runs calcCart function when mediaCB check box is clicked
   document.getElementById("mediaCB").onclick = calcCart();

});

function sessionTest() {
   if (document.getElementById("sessionBox").selectedIndex = -1)
      alert("Select a Session Package");

}

function calcCart() {
   //stores input values in session storage variables
   sessionStorage.setItem('confName', 'document.getElementById("fnBox") + " " + document.getElementById("lnBox")');
   sessionStorage.setItem('confGroup', 'document.getElementById("group")');
   sessionStorage.setItem('confMail', 'document.getElementById("email")');
   sessionStorage.setItem('confPhone', 'document.getElementById("phone")');
   sessionStorage.setItem('confBanquet', 'document.getElementById("banquetGuests")');
   sessionStorage.setItem('confBanquetCost', '55 * document.getElementById("banquetGuests")');
   //checks for selection and stores appropriate values for sessionBox
   if (document.getElementById("sessionBox").selectedIndex = -1) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('confSession', 'document.getElementById("sessionBox")');
      sessionStorage.setItem('confSessionCost', 'indexOf(document.getElementById("sessionBox"))');
   }  else {
      sessionStorage.setItem('confSession', '');
      sessionStorage.setItem('confSessionCost', '0');
   }
   // checks if conference package is included and adjusts cost/value accordingly
   if (document.getElementById("mediaCB").checked) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('confPack', 'yes');
      sessionStorage.setItem('confPackCost', '115');
   } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem('confPack', 'no');
      sessionStorage.setItem('confPackCost', '0');
   }
   sessionStorage.setItem('confTotal', 'parseFloat(confSessionCost) + parseFloat(confBanquetCost) + parseFloat(confPackCost)');
   writeSessionValues();
}

 function writeSessionValues() {
   //writing confItem values to the span text of HTML variables
    document.getElementById("regName").innerHTML = "<script> sessionStorage.getItem('confName')</script>";
    document.getElementById("regGroup").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('confGroup');
    document.getElementById("regEmail").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('confMail');
    document.getElementById("regPhone").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('confPhone');
    document.getElementById("regSession").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('confSession');
    document.getElementById("regBanquet").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('confBanquet');
    document.getElementById("regPack").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('confPack');
    document.getElementById("regTotal").innerHTML = ("$" + sessionStorage.getItem('confTotal')); 
 }
```

```
<section id="section1">
      <form id="regForm" name="regForm" method="post" action="mas_reg2.html">
      <h1>MAS22 Registration Form</h1>
      

         <fieldset id="contactInfo">    
            <label for="fnBox">First Name*</label>
            <input name="firstName" id="fnBox" type="text" required />

            <label for="lnBox">Last Name*</label>
            <input name="lastName" id="lnBox" type="text" required />

            <label for="groupBox">Company or University</label>
            <input name="group" id="groupBox" type="text" />

            <label for="mailBox">E-mail*</label>
            <input name="email" id="mailBox" type="email" required />

            <label for="phoneBox">Phone Number*</label>
            <input name="phoneNumber" id="phoneBox" type="tel" pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$"
                   required placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn" />
         </fieldset>
         
         <fieldset id="confChoices">
            <label for="sessionBox">Session Packs</label>
            <select id="sessionBox" name="sessionOption" size="5" required>
               <option value="95">Exhibits Only ($95)</option>
               <option value="215">3 Session Pack ($215)</option>
               <option value="420">6 Session Pack ($420)</option>
               <option value="595">Session Pass ($595)</option>
               <option value="845">VIP Pass ($845)</option>
            </select>
            <label for="banquet">MAS22 Banquet ($55 ea.)</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="10" id="banquetBox" name="banquetGuests" /><span> attendees</span>          
            
            <label for="mediaPack">MAS22 Media Pack ($115)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mediaPack" id="mediaCB" value="115" />  
               
         </fieldset> 
         <input id="regSubmit" type="submit" value="continue" />
      </form>
   </section>
   
   <aside id="reg1Aside">
      <table>
         <caption>Shopping Cart</caption>
         <tr><th>Name</th><td><span id="regName"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>Company</th><td><span id="regGroup"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>E-mail</th><td><span id="regEmail"></span></td></tr>         
         <tr><th>Phone</th><td><span id="regPhone"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>Session</th><td><span id="regSession"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>Banquet Guests ($55 ea.)</th><td><span id="regBanquet"></span></td></tr> 
         <tr><th>Media Pack ($115)</th><td><span id="regPack"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>TOTAL</th><td><span id="regTotal"></span></td></tr> 
      </table>                                               
   </aside>
```

I have tried to use .toString, enclosed the code in  tags, and combined the two ideas, to no avail.

Comment: What is it that you expect `<script> sessionStorage.getItem('confName')</script>` to do? The session storage call will either retrieve something or it won't, but you don't do anything with the returned value so it's pretty much pointless.

Comment: I am trying to display the value of confName in the span text of regName

Comment: OK but that does not at all answer my question.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused with your question; if you're asking why use <script> it's because otherwise it is displaying the javascript code instead of the value of confName on the webpage. I'm trying to display the live value of confName and can't seem to get it to display and figured it may help to have the <script> tags to run the js within the span tags. Note: this is my first time using sessionStorage, so I'm not sure if that's what's causing my confusion.

Comment: Simply fetching a value from `sessionStorage`, whether it's `null` or not, absolutely will not update the DOM with a value.

Comment: Is there not a straightforward way to display the value of document.getElementById("fnBox") + " " + document.getElementById("lnBox") in the regName text?

Comment: You have to use the browser-provided DOM API methods to change what's shown in the web page. That's pretty much fundamental to using JavaScript in web code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in how you are setting the stored values. You are effectively saving a javascript statement as a string and displaying that string.

`sessionStorage.setItem('confGroup', 'document.getElementById("group")');`, for example will store the string *document.getElementById("group")*

You actually want:

`sessionStorage.setItem('confGroup', document.getElementById("group").value);`

This will retrieve the value from the DOM element. Note the lack of string delimiters in the 2nd parameter and the addition of the `value` property

`document.getElementById("regGroup").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('confGroup');` will now display the stored value.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you have any idea why onblur/onchange may not be working? I added an alert to the calcCart function and it seems that it doesn't get called whenever i am tabbing/clicking through the boxes.

Comment: YOu mayt be better of using `addEventListener` instead of `onBlur` . If you have more than one `onBlur` on an element , only the last one will apply , whereas you can user `addEventListener` as often as you want.